# Is this book in simplified or traditional Chinese?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters, traditional-vs-simplified

To learn Chinese, I'm going to read the Chinese edition of a book I've already read in English. This is it:

[www.amazon.cn/阿特拉斯耸耸肩-安·兰德/dp/B00DA281J2](http://www.amazon.cn/%E9%98%BF%E7%89%B9%E6%8B%89%E6%96%AF%E8%80%B8%E8%80%B8%E8%82%A9-%E5%AE%89%C2%B7%E5%85%B0%E5%BE%B7/dp/B00DA281J2)

Can someone please go into the "See Inside" feature, look at the preview pages, and tell me whether the book is in traditional or simplified Chinese?

Comment: simplified Chinese

Comment: @YangMuye Ok, good. Feel free to post an answer. I've been told learning simplified is a better idea since it's getting more and more popular, especially with the younger generation. Is this right?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is off-topic on this site, so I just posted the answer as comment. Many foreigners learn both simplified and traditional scripts. I think a more important concern is, which dialect you want to learn.

Comment: Well if you look at the "basic info" section on that site, you'll find this text: `语种： 简体中文`. No need to go into the preview.

Comment: Not to start a fight, but if you don't learn/understand traditional (繁體字) as well, then the meaning is largely lost. Simplified (简体字) often swap out parts w/similar pronunciation but unrelated meaning. Makes it harder to guess & understand why characters mean what they do. While you're book shopping, consider this book, which shows stroke order for traditional (important!) as well as the simplified variants http://www.amazon.com/Reading-Writing-Chinese-Traditional-Comprehensive/dp/0804832064/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1403214499&sr=1-4&keywords=learn+chinese+traditional+characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just looking at the title you can tell it's simplified.

Why?

耸 is the simplified version 聳.

Although, technically possible, it's highly unlikely that a book with a simplified title would be "in" traditional.

Comment: And also 兰 is simplified for 蘭.

Answer (score 6):

It is in simplified Chinese, you can see this on the bottom part of the page,
[image]

The sentence in the red frame means: "Language: Simplified Chinese"